# Incorrect user input in textbox is shown by next program start

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a textbox, and two buttons: Confirm and Cancel. If user inputs incorrect text and clicks on Confirm, an error message appears. The user has then two options: input a correct text or click on cancel.
The problem is, if the user inputs incorrect text and then clicks on confirms, the incorrect input is saved and is shown by the next program start.
Could you please help me how to solve this problem? I don't wanna the incorrect input be saved.
I think the problem is with the event for the button Confirm, that's why I post a code for this button event:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ComboBoxFormulas.SelectedIndex == REB91INDEX)
            {
                test.Value1 = txtBox91.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                test.Value1 = txtBox1.Text;
                test.R1 = txtBox2.Text;
                test.Value2 = txtBox3.Text;
                test.R2 = txtBox4.Text;
                test.Value3 = txtBox5.Text;
                test.R3 = txtBox6.Text;
                test.Value4 = txtBox7.Text;
                test.R4 = txtBox8.Text;
                test.Value5 = txtBox9.Text;
                test.R5 = txtBox10.Text;

            }

            if (ComboBoxFormulas.SelectedIndex == COMMENTINDEX)
            {
                test.Value1 = commentBox.Text;
            }


            test.FNr = ((ComboBoxItem)ComboBoxFormulas.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
            try
            {
                test.CalcREB();
            }

            catch(FormulaAssistentException fa)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(fa.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                return;
            }


        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select the formula!", "Warning", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
            return;
        }
        this.Close();
    }
```

EDIT: The variables Value1, Value2 etc. are saved in the another class, and the user input (which is saved in Value1 in my case) has to be saved and shown by the next program start. Only the incorrect input doesn't have to be shown.

Comment: Which part of your code is not working?

Comment: the code I've posted is working correctly, I suggest I miss something in this event in order to solve the problem I've described.

Comment: But your problem isn't described very well or maybe I'm just dumb. I don't know what you mean with "the incorrect input is saved and is shown by the next program start". It's impossible, unless you saved it to some outer file or database and since I don't understand at which line of the code it's saved, I can't suggest you to change a thing. It's just unclear what you're asking from perspective of any other person but you.

Comment: It's not that your problem is complex, it's just described really bad. If you described it any better you'd probably get up to 5 answers by now. Also, it's hard to read anything out of that code itself.

Comment: @msmolcic Sorry for this, I've edited my question and tried to describe the problem more precisely.

Comment: Don't save your value before validating it.

Answer (score 0):

even if it saving and showing in the next run, is a BUG, fix that, since it has no relation with next run as far as I understand your question. 
I seriously cant understand much about your described issue but since you checking the text in the text box and you are using code-behind for that than may be you can try using if text contains what you are trying to search and if it does not matches than don't let it save anything  otherwise as you want you can continue.